# Why scrollView is not working in vertical manner in my code?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

In my react native code I want to show array value with scrolling in vertical manner when I put scrollView horizontal than working fine but actually I need vertical manner.I tried put horizontal false please guide how to fix this problem

{this.state.status ? (

```
             <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled snapToInterval={300} directionalLockEnabled={true} >

          {
             this.state.newArr.map((item, index) => (

                <View  key = {item.id}>
                   <Text style={{color:"green",fontSize:14}} >{item.text}</Text>
                </View>

             ))
          }
       </ScrollView>
        <View style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>
                {this.state.status ? (
                  <View style={styles.SectionStyle2}>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="Type....."
                      ref="textInput"
                      value={this.state.inputValue}
                      maxLength={500}
                      fontSize={14}
                      multiline={false}
                      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                      style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        paddingLeft: 5,
                        paddingRight: 0,

                        paddingTop: 0,
                        paddingBottom: 0
                      }}
                      blurOnSubmit={false}
                      autoFocus={true}
                      onChangeText={msg => this.setState({ msg })}
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() =>
                        this.chatStart(this.doClear(this.viewChat()))
                      }
                    >
                      <Image
                        source={require("./SendMessage-35.png")}
                        style={{ height: 35, width: 35 }}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                ) : null}
              </View>
            </View>
          ) : null}
        </View>
```

I expected array data should be scrollable on vertical manner.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the horizontal attribute is "automatically" true. That is, if it's included, the view will scroll horizontally. Hopefully this means that the default is vertical and simply removing `horizontal` would be enough. (I'm not sure, but this is my impression anyway, which comes partly from looking at this resource):
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Just added nestedScrollEnabled Prop of ScrollView then working ScrollView working perfectly.